# Making a responsive form with headers / changing the layout

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Right now I have a `form` with multiple rows of `inputs` and one set of `labels` placed on top as a header.

[image]

Code:

```
<span id="labels" class="row">
  <span id="labela" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
    <label>Label A</label>
  </span>
  <span id="labelb" class="col-sm-2">
    <label>Label B</label>
  </span>
  <span id="labelc" class="col-sm-2">
    <label>Label C</label>
  </span>
  <span id="labeld" class="col-sm-2">
    <label>Label D</label>
  </span>
</span>

<!-- Input Row 1-->
<span class="row inputRow">
  <span class="inputA" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
    <input type="text">
  </span>
   <span class="inputB" class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text">
  </span>
   <span class="inputC" class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text">
  </span>
   <span class="inputD" class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text">
  </span>
</span>

<!-- Input Row 2-->
<span class="row inputRow">
  <span class="inputA" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
    <input type="text">
  </span>
   <span class="inputB" class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text">
  </span>
   <span class="inputC" class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text">
  </span>
   <span class="inputD" class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text">
  </span>
</span>
```

This works fine, but I'm trying to make it responsive, and for smaller devices I'd like the format to change to having `labels`/`inputs` be inline, like so:

[image]

My question is: Is it possible to change the actual layout responsibly? (All I've seen is changing styling), and if so, how can this be done? Is there a `@media` equivalent for HTML?

I just don't even know the term I'd use to find more resources on this. Ideally I'd like it to not be Javascript dependent (it seems like it would be hacky), unless that's the common way it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Parker** Hi there.

Using a lot less of your code you first have here, you can do that like this.
Just use the Bootstrap `hidden-xx`class.

All I do here is use the first set of code and add your labels to the second row and include these classes.
`<label class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">`

Here is a working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mro6hxv/)**.

```
<div class="container col-lg-12">

    <div id="labels" class="row">
        <span id="labela" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <label>Label A</label>
            <input type="text">
        </span>
        <span id="labelb" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <label>Label B</label>
            <input type="text">
        </span>
        <span id="labelc" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <label>Label C</label>
            <input type="text">
        </span>
        <span id="labeld" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <label>Label D</label>
            <input type="text">
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="labels" class="row spacer">
        <span id="labela" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <label class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">Label A</label>
            <input type="text">
        </span>
        <span id="labelb" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <label class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">Label B</label>
            <input type="text">
        </span>
        <span id="labelc" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <label class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">Label C</label>
            <input type="text">
        </span>
        <span id="labeld" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <label class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">Label D</label>
            <input type="text">
        </span>
    </div>


</div><!-- /.container -->
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I needed.